# How to integral a equidistant curve encircled area

Tags: calculus, geometry

To be specific, the origin curve $y=x^2$ where $-2<x<2$,
then generate a equidistant curve 1 unit below the origin one. then connect the two curve and calculate the area.
The figure of this question is given below

[image: http://chuantu.biz/t6/341/1531362101x-1566688323.jpg]

I have tried the Frenet Frame and got trapped when describing the arc-length.

I can obtain the length of the origin curve is $9.29$.
But I cannot integral the area although I have measured it with some software and known that the answer is $10.62$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrize the portion of curve $y = x^2$ for $-2 \le x \le 2$ by its arc-length ($L$ is the total length)

$$[0,L] \ni s\quad\mapsto\quad p(s) = (x(s), y(s)) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

Let

- $t(s) = p'(s) = (\cos\theta(s),\sin\theta(s))$ be its tangent vector.
- $n(s) = (-\sin\theta(s),\cos\theta(s))$ its normal vector.
- $\kappa(s) = \frac{d\theta(s)}{ds}$ be its curvature.

The region below the curve can be parametrized as

$$[0,L] \times [0,1] \ni (s,\tau)\quad\mapsto\quad p(s) - n(s) \tau \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

If one embed the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that we can use vector products.
The area of above region is given by following integral:

$$
\begin{align}
\verb/Area/ 
&= \int_0^L\int_0^1 | ( p'(s) - n'(s) \tau ) \times n(s) | d\tau ds\\
&= \int_0^L\int_0^1 | (t(s) + \kappa(s)t(s)\tau)\times n(s)|d\tau ds\\
&= \int_0^L 1 + \frac12 \kappa(s) ds
= L + \frac12 \left[ \theta(s) \right]_0^L
\end{align}$$

The first piece

$$L = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + (2x)^2} dx = \frac12\sinh^{-1}4 + 2\sqrt{17} \approx 9.293567524865871$$

is the area you have computed. You have forgotten the contribution from the second piece:

$$\frac12\left[\theta(s)\right]_0^L = \frac12\left[\tan^{-1}(2x)\right]_{x=-2}^2 = \tan^{-1}(4) \approx 1.325817663668033$$

The correct expression for the area should be

$$\verb/Area/ = \frac12\sinh^{-1}4 + 2\sqrt{17} + \tan^{-1}(4) \approx 10.6193851885339$$
This is what you get from your software.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I was trapped at the first step of the area integration. What does the cross product mean? Is it a Jacobian determinant.

Comment: @yddsg It is the Jacobian determinant, when you embed the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Jacobian determinant equals to the magnitude of cross product of partial derivatives of $p$ wrt $s$ and wrt $\tau$ (the standard formula to evaluate the area of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$). i.e. determinant = $\left|\frac{\partial p}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial p}{\partial \tau}\right|$